# How to retrieve all hosted AWS App configurations by environment?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-app-config

I am using AWS APP Config.
I have 2 environments (DEV, PROD).
I couldn`t find how can I retrieve all hosted configuration by environment?
I am using C# and AWSSDK.AppConfig 3.7.102.32

I tried

```
var listConfiguration = await _amazonAppConfig.ListHostedConfigurationVersionsAsync(new ListHostedConfigurationVersionsRequest
{
ApplicationId = _applicationId,
ConfigurationProfileId = configurationProfileId
});
```

But it returns all hosted configuration but cannot differ which one is for PROD or for DEV

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ListDeployments`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/2019-10-09/APIReference/API_ListDeployments.html) to  get all the deployments for an Application using `ApplicationId` and `EnvironmentId`.

```
Lists the deployments for an environment in descending deployment number order.
```

[Example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/AppConfig/MAppConfigListDeploymentsListDeploymentsRequest.html):-

```
var client = new AmazonAppConfigClient();
var response = client.ListDeployments(new ListDeploymentsRequest 
{
    ApplicationId = "339ohji",
    EnvironmentId = "54j1r29"
});

List<DeploymentSummary> items = response.Items;
```